# Unexpected behaviour in formula field (Type - Date)

Tags: apex, soql, formula-field

I am not sure if below is bug in salesforce or is expected behaviour and would like to know reason for same.

If I create a formula field as below

Type - Date  and formula only containing CreatedDate as show in below image.
[image]

I was expecting I will receive error to use DATEVALUE as CreatedDate is *DateTime* field and formula is created with *Date* as type but it was saved.
Moreover on adding same field on all layouts and  checking data in SOQL it only shows Date part of CreatedDate field(DateTime)

Layout :

[image]

SOQL Result:

[image]

Only time I was able to view actual date time value was in Apex.

[image]

Another catch is although it is appearing as Date in SOQL and UI but if you try to query solely by passing date it wont give you result for example :

Query :

```
SELECT Id,Test_Field__c,CreatedDate from account where Test_Field__c = 2022-01-04
```

This will give no results.Unless I use ">" instead of "=" which would make sense only because of time component which somehow gets hidden

Comment: DateTime is auto converted to Date in most scenarios. The other way also happens but beware it creates a DateTime of midnight in UTC, not user timezone.

Comment: Isnt it wrong to allow implicit conversion ?

Comment: It is as it is. Implicit conversion, especially from Date to DateTime, is "dangerous" and something you should avoid relying on. Sadly, it's up to the implementer/developer/admin to be aware and avoid.

Comment: Yep after running across this scenarios ,I realised its a very big gap which a developer might not recognise very easily and needs to be cautious when working around date and date time fields